# Object oriented way to select records from table and store in multi dimensional array

Tags: php, mysql

```
$select = SELECT * FROM `registration_form`;
$sql    = $conn -> query($select);

if ($sql->num_rows > 0) {
    $results = array();
    while ($rows = $sql -> fetch_assoc()) {
    $rows     = $rows['userName'];
    $password = $rows['password'];
    $name     = $rows['name'];
    $address  = $rows['address'];
    $country  = $rows['country'];
    $zipCode  = $rows['zipCode'];
    $email    = $rows['email'];
    $sex      = $rows['sex'];
    $language = $rows['language'];
    $about    = $rows['about'];
    }
} else {
    return false;
}
```

This is normal PHP coding. But I want know how to change to object oriented way and storing variable in multi dimensional way? I am beginner in PHP.

Comment: you have to do like:-`while ($rows = $sql -> fetch_assoc()) {$results[] = $row;}`.Now you have your array,sort it and then use it

Comment: Why not have the database do the sorting for you using `ORDER BY`?

Comment: Thank you so much...sorry for the late reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your array:

```
$results = array();
```

And you have your loop:

```
while ($rows = $sql -> fetch_assoc()) {
```

Just add each row to the array inside the loop:

```
$results = array();
while ($rows = $sql -> fetch_assoc()) {
    $results[] = $rows;
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir...I got it